# Relatively new to PHP, having trouble with showing results from a SQLite DB properly

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

Inserting to database:

> ```
> try {
>   $sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, model, desc, country, privacy) VALUES ('$name', '$model', '$desc', '$country', '$privacy')";
>     $db->exec($sql);
>           echo "New Record Created Succesfully $sql";
>     }
>       catch(PDOException $e) {
>           echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
>  }
> ```

Output:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

the problem i'm having is this only seems to print 1 row from the DB instead of all, I did find using $stmt ->fetchAll(); printed all rows in the DB however the array wasn't working for me, I need it to be associative array. I tried a foreach loop through the FETCH_ASSOC code above but it was skipping DB entries, not really sure what was going on there?

Any help would be appreciated

Thnx.

Comment: you realize that you're using a reserved word

Comment: @Fred-ii- Which? though If you are referring to the what I'm inserting to the table, I edited their proper names a little for this post. They are slightly different in my actual code.. Philipp below helped me with the while, and it works as intended now :)

Answer (score 0):

You could call `PDOStatement::fetch`, till you get `null` as return value. An easy way to achieve this is a simple while-loop

```
while ($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, doing a while loop never crossed my mind. Much appreciated